# An mm of rain or a mm?

Tags: grammar

Even though mm is a shortened form of millimeter, would mm be written as 'an mm' or 'a mm', given that m starts with an 'e' sound.

Comment: In most use cases it's not pronounced as em-em but as millimeters or shortened to 'mil'.

Comment: 'Mm' in a written sentence would normally be spoken as 'millimetre', so I would use 'a mm', or, better still, '1 mm'.

Comment: It depends on if you are pronouncing it *an em em of rain* or *a millimetre of rain*. The indefinite article to use is based entirely on the pronunciation of the noun.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Entirely on whose pronunciation? The reader may have their own ideas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly.

Comment: @Jason Bassford So what does a non-prescient writer write?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A writer can only write what they think the majority of readers would find natural, rephrase anything problematic, or simply write what they want to write. In fact, the specific article used will likely influence reader pronunciation anyway.  I bet very few people would ever pronounce *an mm* as *an millimetre*.